# Center UIImage vertically in Stack View

Tags: ios, autolayout

I've a stackview with an image and another stackview. This sub stackview contains two labels, the username and the tweet text. The tweet text may contain multiple lines.

I'd like the image to be centered vertically within the stackview. If I add a vertically align constraint to the UIImage the stackview takes the height of the image and truncates the twitter text.

Is it possible to vertically align the fixed size image vertically in the stackview without the tweet body being truncated with auto-layout? Or has this be done programmatically?

**Cell**

[image: Image of the table cell]

**Constraints**

[image: Constraints]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `stack.alignment = .center`, if the view is in stack, you should modify the stack properties, and not the `UIView`'s.